# Configuring the URL context

Tags: java, apache, url, spring-boot

I am working on configuring a website where the client wants us to configure URL's like example.com/newyork and example.com/england. We are using Java SpringBoot environment.

Please advise how should I approach this problem? Is this something that can be configured in spring boot/spring-mvc or is an apache configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `@RequestMapping("/myUrl")` on your controller where myUrl should be replaced with the URL you want. 
This should work.